# Get and set USB polling rate

Tags: usb, polling

I programmed a WinAPI c++ application for the communication with a Microcontroller via USB. Now, I get the impression that Windows does poll the USB port at a low rate. How do I get the current USB polling rate of the usb port? How do I increase this rate in my WinAPI c++ application for the USB communication? I did not find much usefull information about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

What interfaces/endpoints do you use?

HID defines the (interrupt) endpoint polling rate in the endpoint descriptor, minimum is 1ms (at full speed or faster).

USB bulk endpoints have just above 1ms communication roundtrip time on average - measured that myself some time ago.

Comment: I am not sure if I can answer your question about the interface/endpoints. I followed the Microsoft help page at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx for building the communication application.